# How to exactly center the figure according to the text?

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, align

I have produced the following page:

[image]

I am tryng to exactly center the figure according to the text above and below. I have already tried the `\centering` and `begin{center}...` options and nothing worked. Is there any way I could achieve this ? Here is the script I have written.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage{floatrow}
%\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes,
                calc}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc,positioning,fit} 
\tikzset{
block/.style={
  draw, 
  fill=blue!20, 
  rectangle, 
  minimum height=3em, 
  minimum width=4em,
  text centered, 
  text width=2cm
  },
sum/.style={
  draw, 
  fill=blue!20, 
  circle, 
  },
input/.style={coordinate},
output/.style={coordinate},
pinstyle/.style={
  pin edge={to-,thin,black}
  }
}  


\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}

\item \textbf{Δοκίμασες να κάνεις αριθμητική παραγώγιση για να εκτιμήσεις την ταχύτητα και να συγκρίνεις με τα αποτελέσματα της εκτίμησης του παρατηρητή?}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Ελεγκτής Πλήρους Ανάδρασης Καταστάσεων}

Έστω ότι επιθυμούμε το σύστημα μας να ανταποκρίνεται στις εξής προδιαγραφές:

\begin{itemize}
\item $ζ = 0.85$
\item $t_s = 2sec$
\end{itemize}

Σε αυτήν την περίπτωση η χρήση της αριθμητικής παραγώγισης για την εκτίμηση της ταχύτητας έχει πάρα πολύ καλά αποτελέσματα σε αντίθεση με τη χρήση της εκτίμησης που παράγεται από τον παρατηρητή. Η εκτίμηση της ταχύτητας μέσω παραγώγισης και από τον παρατηρητή για αυτήν την περίπτωση φαίνεται παρακάτω όπου τα χρώματα αντιστοιχούν:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Μπλε Χρώμα $\rightarrow$ Εκτίμηση Παρατηρητή
\item Κόκκινο Χρώμα $\rightarrow$ Αριθμητική Παραγώγιση
\item Πράσινο Χρώμα $\rightarrow$ \textlatin{Feedback Loop}
\end{enumerate}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\caption{Εκτίμηση Ταχύτητας}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{velocity_estimation_1}
\end{figure}
Παρατηρούμε ότι υπάρχει διαφορά στις εκτιμήσεις της ταχύτητας και ιδιαίτερα σε στιγμές που γίνονται μεγάλες μετατοπίσεις της σφάιρας στη ράβδο. 
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like your image is wider than the text width. I'd try only `width=\textwidth` and remove the other two options.

Comment: Nothing changed. Same result !

Comment: Observe that you inserted an image inside a list and usually the list width is shorter than text width. You can use `\usepackage{showframe}` to see the page margins.

Comment: Also, maybe the image file has a lot of white space around the drawn part. Put the `\includegraphics` in `\fbox{}` to see if this is the case.

Comment: (i) your image is unknown, so we cant use it for test (ii) using `demo` option show, that image occupy (as expected regarding to used size options) whole text area, (iii) from showed images can be concluded that your image has white space on the left side, (iv) try the following: `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.9\textheight,keepaspectratio]{velocity_estimation_1}`.

Comment: Using the proposed solution by @Zarko but for the `0.9\textwidth` option makes it better but in cost of the image size.

Comment: As I said, since the image is within `itemize`, you can not compare the aligment with text above and below since items are not on the left margin. Load `showframe` to see the margins.

Comment: Or maybe what you want is to center the image according to item text above it, not according to the page.

Comment: Using `\usepackage{showframe}` produces what @Sigur says about the margins.

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
\item ...
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{...}
\end{center}
```

Then the image is part of the item text and will be centered within the (indented) `\linewidth` of the item.

However you have wrapped the image in `\begin{figure}` The purpose of that environment is to mark its content as *not* part of the document flow and LaTex ensures that it does not pick up the current `\linewidth` or the current font, it is always normalised to full text width and the default document font.

So it would seem that you simply need to remove `figure` Logically non-floating images do not need a caption either but you could use `\captionof{figure}{...}` from the `capt-of` package if you do want a caption.